# Run instance method with visual studio command while debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I was wondering if there is a trick somewhere to be able to run methods with a visual studio command or something.

For instance, lets say I created a new instance of type `Connection` in `void Main` and saved it to a static variable within the `Program` class. Now, lets say my program is running under the VS2012 debugger, and i would like to arbitrarily execute the method `Connection.Blah(int, string)` on the instance of `Connection` that is held up in my `Program` class from visual studio, with no prior code to do so.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  Use the [Immediate window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx).  Punch in `FullyQualified.Name.To.Program.staticvar.Blah(0, "foo")`, hit enter.

Comment: If i start with a `>` I get `Command "Namespace.Program.connection.method("test")" is not valid.` and if i dont, i get `The expression cannot be evaluated while in run mode. `

Comment: You cannot be in Command mode to do this.  Command mode is the one that starts with ">".  When you get "The expression cannot be evaluated while in run mode." that means that you need to temporarily halt the debugee (by any of the mechanisms to break into the debugger, such as hitting the Break button in Visual Studio or hitting a breakpoint in the program).

Comment: You can only view and manipulate data through the debugger when the debugee (your program) is stopped by the debugger.  Otherwise, the data can change so rapidly that what the debugger presents to you may be stale and/or inconsistent.